# Can Camel File Consumer Read Windows Remote Directory?

Tags: apache-camel

I'm running Camel 2.21.2 in Karaf on Windows Server 2016.

I have a File Producer that is using the directory

```
file://ServerName/ShareName/DirectoryName
```

and this works fine. However, when I try to create a File Consumer in a `pollEnrich` with

```
file://ServerName/ShareName/DirectoryName?fileName=MyFileName.ext&noop=true
```

it is not reading anything and timing out, despite the file being present and accessible.

Is there something in the file consumer that prevents this form of remote access to function, or have I done something wrong in my URL? If the file is local to the server, the pollEnrich works fine.

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the jcifs component:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CAMEL/JCIFS

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache-extras.camel-extra</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jcifs</artifactId>
    <version>${camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Example:

```
smb://login:password@192.168.10.33/inbox?sortBy=file:name&include=.*[.](xml|XML)&delete=true&delay=180000&preMove=inprogress&consumer.bridgeErrorHandler=true
```